# got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word" error only on android devices?

Tags: javascript, android, webpack, webview, chromium

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word       main.bundle.js:109
    ./public/src/main.js                             main.bundle.js:109
    __webpack_require__                              main.bundle.js:20
    (anonymous function)                             main.bundle.js:84
    (anonymous function)                             main.bundle.js:87
```

using webpack and babel (preset-env), works perfectly fine on any other devices, but not working on a android 5.1 device, what could possibly be the problem

main.bundle.js:109:

```
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony import */ var _styles_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./../styles/main.scss */ \"./public/styles/main.scss\");\n/* harmony import */ var _styles_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_styles_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);\n/* harmony import */ var _scenes_battle__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./scenes/battle */ \"./public/src/scenes/battle.js\");\n/* harmony import */ var _scenes_load__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./scenes/load */ \"./public/src/scenes/load.js\");\n// wengwengweng\n\n\n\n\n\nclass Game extends Phaser.Game {\n\n\tconstructor() {\n\n\t\tconst width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;\n\t\tconst height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;\n\n\t\tsuper({\n\n\t\t\twidth: width,\n\t\t\theight: height,\n\t\t\tbackgroundColor: \"#000000\",\n\t\t\tparent: \"game\",\n\t\t\tscene: [_scenes_load__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__[\"default\"], _scenes_battle__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__[\"default\"]],\n\t\t\tphysics: {\n\t\t\t\tdefault: \"arcade\",\n\t\t\t\tarcade: {\n\t\t\t\t\tgravity: 0,\n\t\t\t\t\tdebug: true\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\n\t\t});\n\t}\n\n}\n\nwindow.socket = io();\nwindow.game = new Game();\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./public/src/main.js?");
```

Comment: Post what's at line 109 in your `main.bundle.js` file maybe.

Comment: Well it's hard to read that but the problem is that your babel configuration assumes JavaScript capability that your Android 5.1 target does not support.

Comment: @Pointy is changing a preset a possible solution? what should i use

Answer (score 0):

i switched to parcel bundler and everything works

Comment: Can you share please your solution, i have a similar issue.

Comment: @csgorankings.com i just switched to parcel-bundler for bundling instead of webpack and it works, hope it helps

Comment: hmm, i can't install parcel on windows 10 `'parcel' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: @csgorankings.com i'm not familiar with windows but it should be the same way you install webpack, or just install it locally and either use script to build or use npm script

Comment: okay, i manage to get `parcel` working, but i have a complex structure, i need some configuration options because i managed to build but nothing is showed..., what config did you use?

Comment: @csgorankings.com my config file is like this

const Bundler = require("parcel-bundler");

const entries = [
    // your entries
]

const bundler = new Bundler(entries, {

 outDir: "./public/dist",
 publicUrl: "/dist",
 cache: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
 minify: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
 watch: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"

});

bundler.bundle()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173746/discussion-between-csgorankings-com-and-wengwengweng).